# Import excel file(xls) to R

Tags: r, excel, statistics

I try inset my file to R. But I alway meet problem

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, tabQuote = c("[", "]"), ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code -5016, message [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Reserved error (-5016); there is no message for this error.
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, tabQuote = c("[", "]"), ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 1, message [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x1c68 Thread 0xe00 DBC 0xe398d8c Excel'.
3: In odbcDriverConnect(con, tabQuote = c("[", "]"), ...) :
  ODBC connection failed
```

My code is:

---

```
myfile<-"ds616.xls"
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnectExcel(myfile)
sqlTables(channel)
mydataframe <- sqlFetch(channel, "sheet1")
odbcClose(channel)
```

I check it can't run line 3. plse help me. I check path. It's very ok.

But it's still error.

Comment: Try with the `XLConnect` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using RStudio?

I often encounter this error when working in RStudio:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
    Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] FWDselect_1.1 mgcv_1.7-29   nlme_3.1-117  stringr_0.6.2 sas7bdat_0.4  chron_2.3-45  RODBC_1.3-10
```

Although I can't pinpoint the exact reason why the RODBC package fails to connect to Excel, try rerunning your code in plain R. At the very least this is a workaround solution, until further investigation is made into

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OP is using 32 bit Windows, but this answer may still be informative to users that face problems with `RODBC` under 64 bit Windows.

`RODBC` does not work under Windows 64 bit due to a lack of drivers.
The only solution I am aware of under 64 bit Windows is to save the .xls as .csv and use `read.csv` to import.

Comment: I'm using windows 32 bit

Comment: Then someone else will need to help you, as I run 64 bit and cannot have a look into `RODBC`!